# change the selected text color of the TextField flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, colors, textfield

is there any way to change the selected text color inside a **TextField** in Flutter?
I tried using the controller itself but no much properties to play around with..
Here's a sample of what I want

[image]

is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99231

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextSpan` widget, below a perfect recreation of your sample image

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      // set the default style for the children TextSpans
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(fontSize: 30),
      children: [
        TextSpan(
            text: 'Hello, ',
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Wor',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue
          )
        ),
        TextSpan(
            text: 'ld',
        ),
      ]
    )
  )
```

Comment: but I want it to be editable, select a specific text and then change its color.. how is that possible!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a rich text editor or text field, I don't think flutter supports that out of the box. there are a few libs on pub best I found are [zypher](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr) or [creamy_field](https://pub.dev/packages/creamy_field)
zypher is being re-written on the pre-release might wanna watch out for that

Comment: Thank you so much dear

Answer (score 0):

Within a TextField this would already become difficult, because you do not know what the user enters.
If you are talking about a Text field, you can use RichText

```dart
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          // set the default style for the children TextSpans
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(fontSize: 30),
          children: [
            TextSpan(
                text: 'Styling ',
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'text',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue
              )
            ),
            TextSpan(
                text: ' in Flutter',
            ),
          ]
        )
      )
```

Comment: but I want it to be editable, select a specific text and then change its color.. how is that possible!